# C# textbox alignment issue

Tags: c#, textbox

When I set the alignment of textbox in C# to "Right" I get issue when writing `double` value:

When I press '.' (dot) or ',' (comma) key it remains at left until I press another value:

[image]

What should i do to make it always appears at right?

Comment: Have you tried to write your digits left side of your comma?

Comment: What technology? Win Forms? WPF? Store App? Web Forms? ...

Comment: @SonerGönül sry didn't understand yur question.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Win Forms

Comment: When i'm pressing comma or dot in a TextBox it is coming at the right side only...

Comment: I know, but when you make the alignment of the textbox to the right the comma or dot appears at the left side !

Comment: Maybe in your neck of the world, not in ours.  Be explicit about where you live, it matters if you speak Arabic or Hebrew.  Document your default culture.